# XMPPError: registration-required - auth

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, openfire

when i am join room i am getting exception given below.

> org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPP error
>   reply received from fuu@conference.103.31.81.74/aq: XMPPError:
>   registration-required - auth

```
multiUserChat.join(nickname, password);
```

Comment: Can you post more code here? This information looks not sufficient to understand your problem

Comment: Are you sure the room you are trying to join is created

Comment: room is already created fetched from server.

Comment: the user trying to join is persistent member of the group?, If he is not the member he should be first added to the group by admin N he should be assigned the persistent role.

Comment: please describe some method to add member to group.

Answer (score 2):

The  **registration-required** error on room join means you are trying to join a members only room but you are not in a room member list. In this case the service MUST deny access to the room for you.

Here is a link to XEP-0045 regarding this particular error https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-members

Comment: submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_membersonly", false);
working fine adding above line of code.
Thanks.